# How do I add more workers to Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2

When I'm using server-status to view the number of workers the server can use, its 50 total. What file do I edit to change the maximum number of workers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You edit the Apache configuration file - where that is depends on where and how Apache was installed.  What OS are you on, and how did you install Apache?

To adjust the max worker count, the settings that matter depend on which MPM you're using.  Most likely, you'll need to adjust `MaxClients`, and possibly also `ServerLimit`.

Can you clarify what problem you're looking to solve by changing the maximum worker count?

Comment: Oh, so I need to edit my httpd.conf file?

Comment: Yes - assuming that it's the file containing your current settings for these options.